# Comparing two branches yields different diffs

Tags: git

I used Bitbucket to compare two branches. When I compared my `master` branch (as my source) to my `uat` branch (as my destination) and looked at the diff, I noticed that the list of files are totally different when I compared `uat` (as my source) to `master` (as my destination). There are a lot more files that are different when comparing `master` as my source. Whereas, there are only a few files that are different when comparing `uat` as my source. Why would the order of which I compare differ? Why would the source and destination even matter when comparing two branches?

---

Also, I noticed that most of the files that are listed in the diff have identical content but the only difference is the commit hash.

---

Here are some screenshots. I am using the BitBucket UI to compare the two branches. When letting `master` be my source you can see the settings folder being included in my screenshot which isn't there when I let `uat1` be my source.

[image: uat1 as my source]

---

[image: master as my source]

Comment: What actual commands are you running?  Also, what do you mean "files that are different have identical content but the only difference is the commit hash?"  Individual files don't have a "commit hash".  They *do* have their own object ID (hash), but if the content matches then so will the hash (and, practically speaking, vice versa)

Comment: btw, what I think is happening is, if you're checking out `master` and doing `git diff uat`, then checking out `uat` and doing `git diff master`, and somewhere between `master` and `uat` someone changed the line ending sequence, then depending on your autocrlf settings, what you have in the work tree could differ in one case but not the other.  And this would make the files "look" the same while still calculating different hashes.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I noticed this behavior when I was merging. I did a basic merge command `git merge master` and then when I fixed all the conflicts and looked at my git status I saw a bunch of files that were going to get committed. However, I knew the only changes I made in the uat1 branch were a few files so I compared the two branches in bitbucket and noticed the list of files of the diff were totally different when chosing what source and destination to compare the two.

Comment: When I had uat1 as my source and compared it to master I noticed the correct list of files of changes. But when I had master as my source and compared it to uat1 , the list of files in the diff were around 50. And then I compared some of the files from uat1 and master that were in that list of 50 and noticed that they are identical and the only difference was the hash commit.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Hmm, I see. That is so strange.

Comment: Hmm: are you in the middle of a conflicted merge? Exactly what commands are you running? Can you show the commands and at least a little bit of the output?

Comment: So when you say you compared the branches in bitbucket, do you mean you issued a command via the bitbucket web interface (rather than a command-line `git diff` command, for example)?  If so you should probably tag bitbucket; and also might want to see if you get comparable "weird-ness" comparing the branches locally.  But this seems to deviate from my guess about the problem, so I'm back to "probably need more info"

Comment: @torek I resolved all the merge conflicts. Also, no commands are necessary to see the difference in the compare. What I did was went to bitbucket, clicked on the compare button on the repo . Compared master as the source and uat as the destination. Then I reversed the compare, in the bitbucket UI, and thats how I noticed that huge difference in total files.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Exactly, Mark. I used the UI to compare. And yep I did compare it locally too with the git diff master..uat1 command as same weirdness is happening

Comment: I will post a screen shot

Comment: Screenshot posted

Answer (score 6):

The screen capture you show has a notion of `source` and `destination` branches, and has a `Create pull request` button.

I'm not familiar with Bitbucket GUI, but all git services that offer a Pull Request mechanism (Github, Gitlab (they're called "Merge Requests" in Gitlab), Azure Devops, ...) have a similar view :

the diff that is displayed is :

- the list of changes that `source` would bring in if you merged it into `destination`

which is not the same as  :

- all differences between `source` and `destination`.

---

With a diagram :

```
# say your branches 'master' and 'release/onemsg-uat1' look like this :

       D--E--F <- release/onemsg-uat1  (source)
      /
--*--X--A--B <- master  (destination)
     ^
    fork point, aka "merge base"
```

To represent "the changes brought in by the source branch", rather than looking at the complete diff between `B` and `F`, the GUI presents you with changes starting from `X` :

a. if you open a Pull request to merge `release/onemsg-uat1` (source) into `master` (destination) : the changes to review are the diff between `X` and `F`,
b. if you swap the branches, and look at what `master` would bring to `release/onemsg-uat1` : the changes to review are the diff between `X` and `B`.

---

In `git` terminology, `X` is called the "merge base" of the two branches, and you can get its sha1 with `git merge-base master release/onemsg-uat1`.

One first way to look at those diffs from your local repo is :

```
# changes introduced in release/onemsg-uat1 :
git diff $(git merge-base master release/onemsg-uat1) release/onemsg-uat1

# changes introduced in master :
git diff $(git merge-base master release/onemsg-uat1) master
```

There is a shortcut for the above command : [the three dots notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) `git diff a...b`

```
# changes introduced in release/onemsg-uat1 :
git diff master...release/onemsg-uat1

# changes introduced in master :
git diff release/onemsg-uat1...master
```

To list only the affected files, use `--name-only` or `--name-status` :

```
git diff --name-only master...release/onemsg-uat1
git diff --name-status master...release/onemsg-uat1
```

To open this diff in a graphical diff viewer, use `git difftool` :

```
# the following command will open the differing files one at a time :
git difftool master...release/onemsg-uat1

# with the '-d' option, you will view the diff of two complete directories :
git difftool -d master...release/onemsg-uat1
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: you're using Bitbucket's comparator, which is not `git diff`, and perhaps not even part of Git at all.  It's not obvious what Bitbucket is doing here.  It may or may not be looking at merge bases:

```
base=$(git merge-base $tip1 $tip2)
git diff $base $tip2
```

However, I thought at one point that this is what GitHub was doing for pull request displays, and then experimentation provide that it isn't what GitHub does.  It may not be what Bitbucket does either (nor whether what BitBucket's web-browser-based UI does is directly related to what GitHub's does in the first place).

Since I have no idea what Bitbucket is actually comparing—though it's clearly *not* the two branch tips—I can't really answer the rest of this.  I'll leave the original answer in, below, since it might be useful to others who find this question and really are just running `git diff` on the command line.

---

The input to `git diff` is (to a first approximation anyway) two commits or two snapshots: *compare this snapshot with that one.*

The *output* from `git diff` is a set of instructions.  These instructions tell you *how to **change** the first snapshot, in order to get the second one.*

This means your initial expectation is wrong.  Git is not saying: *To go from an older snapshot to a newer one, add these lines here and remove those there.*  It's saying: *To go from the left side commit/snapshot to the right-side one...*  If you swap the sides, you'll get *inverted* directions: if changing snapshot A to snapshot G requires adding a line, changing snapshot G into snapshot A will require deleting that same line.

Comment: I should clarify. I meant to say that the list of diff files are totally different. When I have master as my source there are a lot of files that where committed when I merged but when I had uat as my source there were only a couple of files that were committed