# Failed to get all commited changed files in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have two branches, one is `master`, the other is `feat/test`. For some reason, I have to get all changed files in multiple commits of a merge request in gitlab-ci.yml.
So I wrote the script like this:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
    - export CHANGED_FILES="`git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r origin/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}`"
    - echo "All changed files are below"
    - echo "${CHANGED_FILES}"
```

The `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` can be logged, which is `master`. However, I couldn't get the `CHANGED_FILES` or `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`. They just logged nothing.
So is there any way to get all commited changed files in gitlab-ci.yml? I have checked many solutions in the gitlab forum but none of them worked for me.

Comment: @LeGEC I am sure the pipeline is triggered by a merge request(from feat/test to master)

Comment: @LeGEC Actually I only want to get the file name so `--name-only` is enough.

Comment: @LeGEC Where should I print it? Before executing the `git diff`？

Comment: @LeGEC I have logged all env variables. And it is strange that I can't find variable `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: @LeGEC. Maybe I know way. I have thought that 'merge request trigger' means the pipeline is triggered after I successfully merge one branch to another branch. But not, it actually means the pipeline is triggered once there is an open merge request produced.

Comment: I basically grouped my comments together as an answer, am now deleting the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that, when your pipeline runs, the active branch (`$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`) is "master" could be an indication that the job you are looking at was not triggered in response to a merge request event, but to some other event (`master` being updated through other mean, for example).

The fact that `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` is missing from the environment (you provided this information in a comment) would confirm this indication.

---

For debugging purposes, much like you added `echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` and `echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`, you could have your pipeline print the complete set of environment variables in its logs:

```
script:
  - env
  - export CHANGED_FILES="`git diff ...
```

a word of caution: your CI environment may contain credentials, running `env` would make these credentials readable in the logs of said jobs.

I do not recommend to keep this debugging instruction in your final pipeline, and you may want to filter out values (`env | grep -v MYAPP_PASSWORD | grep -v MYDATABASE_PASSWORD`) or to restrict the set of variables (for example: `env | grep -e "^CI_"`)

Do also inspect the information in the gitlab GUI to understand what triggered the job you are looking at.

---

One side note worth mentioning:

if you want to spot the files modified by a pull request, you should use:

```
git diff --name-only <target branch>...<source branch>
```

(that's three dots, not a typo -- link to [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1))

Here are more details about that point (note: shameless self plug):
[Comparing two branches yields different diffs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66789252/86072)

Comment: When executing `git diff --name-only origin/master...feat/test
`, I got another error saying "gitlab diff fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...feat/test': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: CI runners often try to be smart about limiting the amount of data downloaded from your git repo (shallow clones, download only selected references ...) so you may not have the full information. To debug: `git branch -a` will show you what branches are known, `git config --get-all remote.origin.refspec` will describe what is downloaded by default when running `git fetch`. To download a missing branch: `git fetch`, or `git fetch origin +master:refs/remotes/origin/master`.

Comment: I have successfully got all names of changed files in a merge request pipeline. The problem is that I need to use these file names on another pipeline, which is triggered after the merge request pipeline. So I used artifacts to transform these names between 2 seprate pipelines. But it seems the second pipeline can't read the artifact file content from the first pipeline.

Comment: I suggest to ask another question, where you explain more precisely your issue (e.g: what step after the merge request ? what do you need the list of files for ? etc ...)

Comment: hi, LeGEC, I have asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410929/how-to-access-the-artifact-file-of-pipeline-a-in-pipeline-b-at-gitlab-ci-yml