# How to access the artifact file of pipeline A in pipeline B at gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I have created a project which uses sdk to upload files to some places. To implement incremental updates, which can upload the changed files instead of all files each time, I have to figured out which files change every time when there is a merge reuqest happens.

So there is a first pipeline named pipeline A. It is triggered when a merge request happens. Like this:

```yaml
stages:
 - get_diff_files

get_diff_files:
  stage: get_diff_files
  script:
    - git fetch --depth 1 origin $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA
    - git diff-tree --name-only -r $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA > diff_files.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - diff_files.txt
    expire_in: 1 week  
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Here I use `git diff` to figure out the changed files and store the result to a file named `diff_files.txt`.

Next, there is a second pipeline named pipeline B. It is triggered once the merge request is merged. So the pipeline B must run after pipeline A. They are two different separete pipelines.

And the gitlab-ci.yml is:

```yaml
stages:
 - get_diff_files
 - upload

get_diff_files:
  stage: get_diff_files
  script:
    - git fetch --depth 1 origin $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA
    - git diff-tree --name-only -r $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA > diff_files.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - diff_files.txt
    expire_in: 1 week  
  only:
    - merge_requests
upload:
  stage: upload
  script:
    - export CHANGED_FILES=$(cat get_diff_files/diff_files.txt)
    - echo "The changed files are"
    - echo "${CHANGED_FILES}"
    - yarn
    - yarn upload 
 dependencies:
    - get_diff_files
```

Here I use `cat` to access the artifact file from pipeline A. And the problem is that, when pipeline B runs and executes the `cat`, the gitlab CI throw an error saying that no such file. It seems the pipeline B can't access the `diff_files.txt`. So is there any way to access the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sync the content of two directories: you may use a dedicated tool, like `rsync`, which is probably already available in your runner.

---

If `master` moves forward only one commit at a time: `git diff --name-only master~ master` or `git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD` should do the job.

You talk about uploading files: you may need to distinguish between *files to upload* (new and modified files) and *files to delete* :

```
# the following files should be copied over:
git diff --no-renames --diff-filter=AM master~ master
# the following files have been deleted:
git diff --no-renames --diff-filter=D master~ master
```

---

If `master` may also be modified by direct pushes, which may bring several commits at once in master: you will need to choose a way to mark the latest commit that was uploaded.

One way could be to upload a file which contains the sha of the latest commit that was uploaded:

```
# would be script:
  script:
    ...
    - yarn
    - yarn upload
    - git rev-parse HEAD > uploaded-commit.txt && yarn upload uploaded-commit.txt
```

another way could be to update a tag or a branch (or any ref) on your repo :

```
  script:
    ...
    - yarn upload
    - git tag -f upload/latest && git push origin -f upload/latest
```

You may then get that value back on your next run, and compare `HEAD` with that latest commit, instead of comparing it to `HEAD~`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I just want to know how to access an artifact file which records the changed files in another pipeline.